# Call PHP file From Script from PHP File

Tags: javascript, php

I want to call PHP file which includes javascript (Adsense code) so that that the ad appears between image and download button. but it didn't work

page.php

```
<?php

   if($_POST) { $result = '
       <img class="result-img img-responsive center" id="Div_contain_image" src="'.$variable.'/media/?size=l" alt="Instagram private Photo Downloader">

      <include "./inc/ad.php">

<a class="gemiano gemiano-large center"  id="Div_contain_image" style=" margin-top: 16px;" href="'.$variable.'/media/?size=l" download="'.$variable.'/media/?size=l" onclick="prepHref(this)">Download</a> '; 
  echo $result; }

?>
```

ad.php

```
                           <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                               style="display:block"
                               data-ad-client="ca-pub-7777090103100866"
                               data-ad-slot="3284678003"
                               data-ad-format="auto"
                               data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
                           <script>
                               (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                           </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

A good way to implement this is breaking `<?php ?>` like that

```
<?php
   if($_POST) {
 ?>
       <img class="result-img img-responsive center" id="Div_contain_image" src="<?php echo $variable; ?>/media/?size=l" alt="Instagram private Photo Downloader">
      <?php include "./inc/ad.php" ?>
      <a class="gemiano gemiano-large center"  id="Div_contain_image" style=" margin-top: 16px;" href="<?php echo $variable ?>/media/?size=l" download="<?php echo $variable ?>/media/?size=l" onclick="prepHref(this)">Download</a>

<?php
    echo $result; 
  }
?>
```

Comment: @MrUpsidown - Not really. It would look just fine. This is probably the only right way to use little PHP within lot of HTML.